# Why can't I use SimpleGeo through a URL?

Tags: json, geolocation, google-api

So, Google Places API allows me to receive JSON data through a Google Places API search using a simple:

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=50&client=clientId&sensor=true_or_false&signature=SIGNATURE"

(note, includes signature/key).

Why does SimpleGeo not allow this same feature?  Is it possible?  What is the purpose of all of this server side code that SimpleGeo uses?

Regards, 
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

SimpleGeo has recently announced a [JavaScript SDK](http://simplegeo.com/docs/clients-code-libraries/javascript-sdk), which includes a JSONP API. This should allow you to do exactly what you're asking -- requesting read-only information from their Context and Places APIs purely from the client side with a simple key to authenticate the request.

I think there are still plenty of purposes for accessing SimpleGeo's data from a server-side application -- not all developers are writing purely JavaScript client-side applications -- but I agree that this new SDK will help a lot of developers.

Also, if you're looking for straightforward REST access to JSON resources without any client libraries, that's also present. See SimpleGeo's documentation on [API endpoints](http://simplegeo.com/docs/api-endpoints).